# Java Problems - Scanner Input and If (X == Input) Statements

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

I just read through seven threads related to Java Scanner issues, but none contained the answer to my problem.

I'm trying to get user input form the console. I create a Scanner object (input) then try to store the user's command in a string called "command." Then I pass "command" back to the original runGame function. It seems that Scanner/command do read the write text. (If I enter 'd' and then print command's contents it prints 'd'.)

But when I return the string and store it in nextMove, it breaks. For example, I'll enter 'd' but then (nextMove == 'd') if statement isn't called. In fact, no matter what I enter, only the else statement is entered.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it**

Here's the original function code:

```
public void runGame() {
        drawWindow();
        while(true) {
            String nextMove = takeInput();
            if(nextMove == "d")
                System.out.print("WORRRRDDD d");
            else if(nextMove == "w")
                System.out.print("WORRRRDDD w ");
            else {
                drawWindow();
                System.out.print("YOU GOT ELSED");
                continue;
          }
        }
}
```

And here's the takeInput/Scanner function code:

```
public String takeInput() {
    String command;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);     // "input" is the Scanner object used for all input.
    try{
        System.out.print("Enter command (d, w, stop, restart, exit):  ");
        command = input.next();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You entered an invalid command.");
        return null;
    } 
    System.out.println("\n RETURNING COMMAND" + command + " \n");
    return command;
}
```

**While you're helping (I'm going to search but if I don't find it) what's the best way to recognize blank input in a scanner object?**

**And should are there any other exceptions/catches I need to worry about for user input in a console?**

Comment: I maybe wrong but i dont think java string statements are done with ==

Comment: Wait a minute, it's because I need to use .equals() isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `==`, use `.equals(String)`, so your check would look like:

```
if(nextMove.equals("d"))
```

`==` checks that the variables are the exact same reference in memory, `.equals()` checks that the two instances are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, use .equals when checking for equality between Strings.

Furthermore, whenever you have a constant in your equality check you should put it first. e.g.

```
"abc".equals(someString);
```

This will only ever be a boolean. Whereas:

```
someString.equals("abc");
```

This can be a boolean or throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldnt be using == for string comparison , if i remember correctly use compare, compareTo or equals.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use "==" method to compare 2 String objects. You will need to use .equals() method.

Your changed part of code should look like :

```
    if(nextMove.equals("d"))
        System.out.print("WORRRRDDD d");
    else if(nextMove.equals("w"))
        System.out.print("WORRRRDDD w ");
```

**Why ?** referenced from [here](http://www.java-tips.org/blog/java-se/using-or-equals-for-string-comparision.html)

> The “==” operator compares two object
>   references to see whether they refer
>   to the same instance. It checks
>   whether two objects are exactly the
>   same object or not. Two strings may be
>   different objects, but can have the
>   same value (have exactly the same
>   characters in them). In such case,
>   “==” will return false.
>
> Take special care when comparing
>   objects. If you wish to see whether
>   two objects are same or not, then
>   use”==” to, or use equal() to see if
>   they have the same value.

Also check following links:

http://www.zparacha.com/java-string-comparison/

http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-string-comparison